# Next.JS v13 in Docker does not respect path alias but works locally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, next.js, dockerfile

I had a working docker build and when I put in absolute paths with a path alias, it suddenly started complaining `module not found, can't resolve 'ComponentName'`

It will fail at the `pnpm run build` step, but when I run it locally, it works fine.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The file causing the error:

```
import { Providers } from './providers';
import NavBar from '~/components/NavBar';
import { css } from '~/styles/css';

import './global.css';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'p-stack-fs',
  description: 'A boilerplate for TypeScript, Next.js, and PostgreSQL',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <div className={css({ minH: '100vh' })}>
            <NavBar />
            {children}
          </div>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

Error:

```
 > [builder 6/6] RUN pnpm run build:
#25 0.534
#25 0.534 > p-stack-fs@0.1.0 build /app
#25 0.534 > next build
#25 0.534
#25 0.940 - warn You have enabled experimental feature (instrumentationHook) in next.config.js.
#25 0.941 - warn Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
#25 0.941
#25 1.010 - info Creating an optimized production build...
#25 10.94 Failed to compile.
#25 10.94
#25 10.95 ./src/app/layout.tsx
#25 10.95 Module not found: Can't resolve '~/components/NavBar'
#25 10.95
#25 10.95 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
#25 10.95
#25 10.95 ./src/app/layout.tsx
#25 10.95 Module not found: Can't resolve '~/styles/css'
#25 10.95
#25 10.95 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
#25 10.95
#25 10.95
#25 10.95 > Build failed because of webpack errors
#25 11.09  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pnpm run build]: exit code: 1
```

You can see the files exist and are named properly here:

[image]

FWIW, here's my Dockerfile

```
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.17

FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY panda.config.ts ./

RUN npm i -g pnpm && pnpm i --prod --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# Panda is built in the `prepare` command, which runs after
# `install`, so we copy it over here for building
# COPY --from=deps /app/src/styles/ ./src/styles/

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM alpine:${ALPINE_VERSION} AS runner

WORKDIR /app

# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN apk add --no-cache --update nodejs
# Get AWS SSM Params using a Go binary, reduces image size
# Note: this might get a "8: not found" error if not using the USER nextjs, has
# to do with something with the ca-certificates
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
RUN wget https://github.com/pthieu/go-aws-get-parameter/raw/master/ssm_get_parameter
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./ssm_get_parameter"]

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/static ./.next/static
# COPY --from=builder /app/src/db/migrations ./migrations

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/docker-entrypoint.sh ./

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 80

ENV PORT 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
# For debugging, keeps container alive
# CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the issue.

The solution was to update `next.config.js` to set the path alias in webpack. This should be the same as your `tsconfig.json`.

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.resolve.alias['~'] = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
    return config;
  },
};
```

Here's my hypothesis: in Next.js 13, they moved to turbopack but still use Webpack as a bundler. Webpack runs at a different phase than the TS compilation phase, so it doesn't take into account `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thanks I found some solutions but none worked for me.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure out why it would build locally but not within Docker. This fixed it for me too - much appreciated!

For other hitting this, don't forget to `const path = require('path')`

Comment: @PGT the real solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/77621486/6141587

Answer (score 3):

In my case, we were using DigitalOcean's App platform to build a Next app and the issue was that development dependencies weren't being installed as we had `NODE_ENV=production`. By default, NPM will ignore dev dependencies when it sees that environment variable set.

Unfortunately, dev dependencies critically included TypeScript and so settings we had in our `tsconfig.json` had no effect (which included the important setting: `compilerOptions.paths`).

Solution was to change the build command from `npm run build` to `npm install --production=false && npm run build && npm ci` which ensured development dependencies were installed and used for build.

Comment: That was exactly my issue - in new versions of Next.js, TypeScript is added as a dev dependency by default so `@/...` imports are not resolved correctly when deploying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My case is that when I changed the casing of a directory, Git ignored this change. As a result, the local file path has the first letter in lowercase, while the remote has it in uppercase. This causes issues in the pipeline during build, as the import cannot be found. To confirm if you're in the same situation, first check the Git configuration with

```
git config core.ignorecase
```

If it is set to true, then you need to verify if the casing of the paths causing the compilation errors is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar cannot find module error in github actions, though not in a docker environment.

In my case, the problem was a case modifying the filename.

I am currently using MacOS, and MacOS is not case sensitive, so changing the case of the filename does not cause problems when building, but in the ubuntu environment, it is case sensitive.

If you have changed the case,You can check file name on github to see whether there is any different in letter case.

If this is because of renaming then try below command.

```
git rm -r --cached . && git add --all .
```