# Module not found: Can't resolve '@/...' in Docker (Next.js)

Tags: docker, next.js, next.js13

I'm building my Next.js v.13.5.4 to Docker but I got this error message

Error Message

```
./app/page.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/ui/select'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

After futher investigation, I found this [Github issues](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8452) and I have added the following code to my next.config.js but nothing seems to change.

Here is my next.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.join(__dirname)

    return config;
  },
  output: 'standalone',
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
...
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@/schema/*": ["schema/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["types/*"],
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# Install yarn
# RUN apk add yarn
RUN npm install yarn@1.22.19
 
# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn cache clean
 
# Copy the application code
COPY / ./
 
# Set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3000
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=ENDPOINT
# Disable Next.js telemetry https://nextjs.org/telemetry
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
 

# Build the application
RUN yarn build
 
# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000
 
# Start the application
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Note that starting Next.js locally works (both dev and build) as well as starting Docker from this Dockerfile. This does not work inside a Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: Does the path equals the paths specified in tsconfig.json? I had the same problem. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76676456/next-js-v13-in-docker-does-not-respect-path-alias-but-works-locally) helped me.

Comment: Hi! I have editted my question. Here is my tsconfig.json. Please have a look

Comment: I would try to add every path from tsconfig to next.config.js as

 ```config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.join(__dirname, "constants")```  etc.

Or I would try to replace all paths in tsconfig with 

```"@/*": ["./*"]```,